# Android soft kyeboard: how do I make buttons at bottom of my layout (say, like SAVE, CANCEL etc) always visible, even with the soft keyboard enabled?

Tags: android, button, show, android-softkeyboard, always-on-top

I am sure there must be a simple way for this, but I havent found an answer yet.

Let me further explain. My activity (looks like an application form) has a good number of EditText and buttons, their numbers vary during the run. So, although they are always in a ScrollView, they might not always be enough of them to actually scroll on them. That said, there are a few buttons at the bottom of my layout which I want to be always visible, irrespective of whether the soft keyboard is visible or not. Currently clicking on an EditText pops up the soft keyboard and hides the buttons at the bottom.

Note, I have already tried using Relative Layout and AdjustPan options unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So you've tried AdjustResize as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can read the full story [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html)